# <> (not equal) is not working in a simple access query

Tags: ms-access

I have the following query where I want to pull all active employees where their CardStatus <> "Lost Card".

```
SELECT
    dbo_Employee.Status, 
    dbo_EmpBadgeNumbers.EmployeeID_FK, 
    dbo_EmpBadgeNumbers.CardID, 
    dbo_EmpBadgeNumbers.CardStatus 
FROM dbo_Employee INNER JOIN dbo_EmpBadgeNumbers 
        ON dbo_Employee.EmployeeID = dbo_EmpBadgeNumbers.EmployeeID_FK 
WHERE (((dbo_Employee.Status) = "Active") 
    AND ((dbo_EmpBadgeNumbers.CardStatus) <> "Lost Card"));
```

If I replace the <> "Lost Card" with "Lost Card" it works,

If I replace the <> "Lost Card" with is null it works (which gives the result I'm looking for)

If I replace the <> "Lost Card" with is not null it works.

For whatever reason it doesn't like the "<>". Yes I know I can just use the "is null" scenario to get the same result, I'm curious as to why the <> is not working. If it matters the query is pulling from a linked ODBC connection to sql server.

Comment: What is the full query? Are there any other conditions in the were clause?

Comment: Please post your _complete_ SQL statement. Best to copy 'n paste from your workspace rather than retyping in, just in case there's a subtle error you're missing.

Comment: Just to be clear are you expecting `<> "Lost Card"` to match `NULL` values?

Comment: SELECT dbo_Employee.Status, dbo_EmpBadgeNumbers.EmployeeID_FK, dbo_EmpBadgeNumbers.CardID, dbo_EmpBadgeNumbers.CardStatus
FROM dbo_Employee INNER JOIN dbo_EmpBadgeNumbers ON dbo_Employee.EmployeeID = dbo_EmpBadgeNumbers.EmployeeID_FK
WHERE (((dbo_Employee.Status)="Active") AND ((dbo_EmpBadgeNumbers.CardStatus)<>"Lost Card"));

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting the results to be all null for the card status field. And thats the issue huh, I can't pull all the nulls by the <> 'Lost Card". First time using sql for tables, must treat null and "" differently. Never had this issue with strickly using Access for tables. Thanks all!

Comment: The better way to do this is to have a positive value for the CardStatus (like "Valid") and the search for `CardStatus = "Valid"`. This way it culls out the "Lost Card"'s and the nulls, and if you add a new status (like "Suspended") you don't have to rewrite your queries to handle them as well.

Comment: If the field really has only two values, it should be a Boolean. On the other hand, if you make it a Boolean and the users later invent a new "card status" you'll have to make a change. I think your instincts are right and you should test for `<>"Lost Card" And Is Not Null`. But you should consider whether or not you have the right data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing Null to anything will simply return Null:

```
?Null<>"Lost Card"
Null

?Null="Lost Card"
Null
```

You need to do an explicit check for Null in your criteria:

```
WHERE (CardStatus <> "Lost Card" Or CardStatus Is Null)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would then try

```
CardStatus is null
OR NOT ( CardStatus = "Lost Card" )
```

The original NOT CardStatus = "Lost Card" would NOT equate as

```
(NOT CardStatus) = "Lost Card"
```

as its base type is that of character so would be compared based on the "=", then apply the logical NOT... such as

```
NOT (CardStatus = "Lost Card")
```

Comment: That would be evaluated as (NOT CardStatus) = "Lost Card"

Comment: even if you did Not( CardStatus = "Lost Card"), it would still fail because `CardStatus = Null` evaluates to `Null` and `not(null)` evaluates to `null` which results in a false result.

Answer (score 1):

<> never does work with Null.

**Incorrect:** WHERE CardStatus <> Null
**Correct:** WHERE CardStatus Is Not Null

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have two values in CardStatus: "LostCard" and `null` (empty)

Basically, when you do ANY comparison against `null` the result is always `null` and is always a failure. This is the reason why isNull was created.

Comment: Actually, the IsNull() function is not really relevant here. If you really only had two valid values, "LostCard" and Null, then you'd only need to test for `Is Not Null` to get the lost cards. Using the SQL `Is Null` operator will utilize indexes, whereas using the IsNull() function may prevent the use of them.